# Can we develop and deploy WSRP producer on not portlet container?

Tags: portlet, spring-portlet-mvc, wsrp

if the WSRP producer is a web service but with specific WSDL form and request and response contains HTML, can we develop WSRP producer to be deployed on just web container without using portlet container for producing WSRP.

Answer (score 0):

Since WSRP is a standard you should be able to code to the standard and make a web application that is compliant with it. So I would say yes you can, but I feel like it would be a relatively large and involved project compared to just making a portlet application and installing a portlet container that already implements the WSRP standard.

It would be the same thought process as "HTTP is standard, can we write our own HTTP library?" Yes you can but someone else has already done that difficult work in creating one so you would have to come up with a very good justification to want to write your own.